# Plotting two columns from multiple data frames on one graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a bunch of .txt files in a folder.  Each have different data with the same column title for each column.  I have looped through all of the files turned them into separate dataframes and stored them in a dictionary.  I would like to basically merge all the time columns together and plot the different pressures on the same graph on the y axis.  So I would have x=merged times, and y all the different pressures.  Could someone help me figure this out thank you in advance for any help with this.

Here is the heads of one of the txt files:

```
[15191 rows x 4 columns], 'Stg2_ASCII.txt':            TIME  Pressure  Rate  Prop_con
0      00:00:00       146  16.8       0.0
1      00:00:00       152  16.8       0.0
2      00:00:00       153  16.9       0.0
3      00:00:00       152  16.8       0.0
4      00:00:00       153   9.9       0.0
```

#all dataframes stored in here

```
combine = {}


for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=range(0,2))
        df = pd.DataFrame({
                "TIME": data._get_column_array(1)
                ,"Pressure": data._get_column_array(2)
                ,"Rate": data._get_column_array(6)
                ,"Prop_con": data._get_column_array(8)
            })

    
        combine[filename] = df
```

Comment: Does my answer provide the solution you were looking for or do you need more explanations?

Comment: Not really, bc if I use append then it will just add the data to the bottom and I will have no way to differentiate pressure data sets from each stage from one another.  I believe I need to use pd.merge so I can then rename the different pressure columns to pressure1, pressure2, and merge them on the key time.

Comment: I see that I misunderstood the question, sorry about that. I have updated my answer, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [join method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) which is slightly more convenient to use than the merge method in this case. As you want to plot the data according to time, it makes sense to set `TIME` as the index from the beginning. This makes `join` convenient to use seeing as it merges dataframes on the index by default. The columns of the first dataframe can be renamed for consistency in the numbering.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd  # v 1.2.3

combine = {}
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=range(0,2))
        df = pd.DataFrame({
            "Pressure": data._get_column_array(2),
            "Rate": data._get_column_array(6),
            "Prop_con": data._get_column_array(8)
            },
            index=data._get_column_array(1))
        combine[filename] = df

# Select first dataframe and then merge others to it on the index, using
# outer merge in case the time ranges are not identical in all files
dfm = list(combine.values())[0]
for idx, df_other in enumerate(list(combine.values())[1:]):
    dfm = dfm.join(df_other, how='outer', rsuffix=idx+2)

# Rename first columns for naming consistency
dfm.columns = [col+'1' if idx < df_other.columns.size else col
               for idx, col in enumerate(dfm.columns)]

# Plot all pressures
dfm[dfm.columns[['Pressure' in col for col in dfm.columns]]].plot()
```

Comment: That worked beautifully man, now I just need to truly understand what you did.  Thanks for the help.